# React SPA: Pass Authorization Header to fetch api call

Tags: reactjs, nginx, authorization, basic-authentication, fetch-api

I have a React single page application running on a nginx-webserver. The Nginx is configured that accessing my application the first time after the browser was started the user gets the browser basic auth login window (auth_basic setting in the location-part of the nginx config file). The user enters name and password and another request to the server gets send including the authorization header. So far so good.

Now in my react application i want to call different REST-Apis via fetch api:

```
fetch("URL", {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: new Headers({
                // 'Authorization': "THIS SHOULD BE SET SOMEHOW",
            }),
            body: "SOME_DATA"
        }).then((response: any) => {
            ...
        })
```

How can I access the existing authorization header from the initial page call after the user has logged in to use it in my REST-Api call?

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in(`The user enters name and password and another request to the server gets send including the authorization header`) the first time you should store the `Authorization` token in either LocalStorage, SessionStorage and get the token from there and set it to Heders.

Clean approach: You can create a Helper Class/Function(interceptor). that will take care of adding a header and common things.

```
// Something like this Not 100% perfect

class HttpService {
    _getHeaders(){
        // Logic to get header from Storage
        return {'Authorization': "THIS SHOULD BE SET SOMEHOW"};
    }

    _apiHandler(url, options){
        return fetch(url, {
            headers: new Headers({
              ...this._getHeaders(),
            }),
            ...options,
        });
    }

    post(){
       return this._apiHandler("URL", {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: 'include',
            body: "SOME_DATA"
        });
    }
}
```

**OR**

**Recommended:**
Ask the backend team to send tokens in the cookies, You don't have to do anything browser will take care of that. **Only same domain request**

**NOTE:** you could share a cookie between **foo.example.com** and **bar.example.com** but never between **example.com** and **example2.com** and that's for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your support. 
The question is: How can I access the authorization header? I havent found any possibility to access the exeisting authorization header.

The react app and the REST-Apis are in different domains. My approach is only a workaround for switching to real security systems like keycloak in the future.

Comment: When User `The user enters name and password and another request to the server gets send including the authorization header`. That auth header you have to store in local/session storage.

Comment: The username and password gets entered in a browser popup, not in self written input fields. I am not shure how to save the data in the local/session storage.

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Comment: Sorry if I missunderstand you. I know how to access local/session store and how to put data in it.
If you can show me how to console log the header part 'authorization: basic XXX', then I am fine. The rest would be clear to me, but I dont see a chance to access the authorization header